# Clear dropdown Select2 populated from JSP / Ajax with a button only works once

Tags: javascript, ajax, jsp, jquery-select2

I have a page in which to make a query to the database, 12 filters are applied (each filter corresponds to a select2 dropdown).

When the page loads, the selects are filled by default with data from the java controller.

Example from a jsp page:

```
<select id="selectFPA" name="selectFPA" form="formResult" class="form-control">
    <option selected>All the results</option>
    <c:forEach items="${fpaList}" var="fpaList">
        <option><c:out value="${fpaList.fpaname}" /></option>
    </c:forEach>
</select>
```

But, if the user selects any value in any of the filters, all the filters are updated based on the chosen selection, through an AJAX call.

For example, suppose we have two select filters (dropdown):

Select 1 (Animal group):
- Birds
- Mammals

Select 2 (Animal name):
- Parrot
- Dog

If the user chooses mammals, an AJAX function will be called that will query the database and update the content of the select 2, eliminating the Parrot option. (And so on with up to 12 filters).

The problem comes when I want to clear the applied filters and return to the original select content (the content that appears by default every time the page is loaded from the java controller).

I have tried many things, from similar Stackoverflow questions without success.

The last thing I tried was:

1. Save the initial content of the select in a variable:

   `const fpa = $("#selectFPA").find("option").clone();`
2. Onclick event (Reset filters button)

```
        $("#ResetFilters").on("click",function() {
            //first we empty the content  
            $('#selectFPA').empty().trigger('change.select2');
            //original value injection
            $("#selectFPA").html(fpa),
            $('#selectFPA').trigger('change.select2')
        })
```

This works fine if I press the button once, if I press the button a second time, the selects randomly select different values by default and they behave strangely.

I know this is a very specific question, but could someone help me? What am I doing wrong?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think as per [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21073156/jquery-constants-as-variables-for-calling-functions/21074195#21074195) answer you cannot create constant in jquery that's the reason only first time it works and next time it doesn't .Alternate, solution might be assign that `clone` value to some `div` and fetch it anytime when needed.Like below :

```js
//call when page loads for the first time
$(document).ready(function() {
  //cloning
  var fpa = $("#selectFPA").find("option").clone();
  //assigning value to div
  $("#abc").html(fpa);


  $("#ResetFilters").on("click", function() {

    //getting clone value from div
    var c = $("#abc").find("option").clone();
    //first we empty the content  
    // $('#selectFPA').empty().trigger('change.select2');
    //original value injection
    $("#selectFPA").html(c);
    //$('#selectFPA').trigger('change.select2')
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="selectFPA" name="selectFPA" form="formResult" class="form-control">
  <option selected>All the results</option>
  <option>1</option>
  <option>2</option>

</select>

<button id="ResetFilters">Reset</button>
<div id="abc" style="display:none"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much, it is an interesting option. I'm going to try implementing it for all filters and I'll let you know if it works!

Comment: Okey, it worked, but in my case I needed to trigger using:

```$('#selectFPA').trigger('change.select2')``` 
Now it works perfectly, thanks!